# raw_input() and sys.stdin misbehaves on CTRL-C

Tags: python, exception, raw-input

I am trying to detect a KeyboardInterrupt exception when CTRL-C is pressed during a raw_input() prompt. Normally the following code works just fine to detect the command:

```
try:
    input = raw_input("Input something: ")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    do_something()
```

The problem comes when trying to intercept the input from sys.stdin. After adding some code in between raw_input() and sys.stdin, the CTRL-C command now results in two exceptions: EOFError followed by KeyboardInterrupt a line or two later. This is the code used to test:

```
import sys
import traceback

class StdinReplacement(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stdin = sys.stdin
        sys.stdin = self
    def readline(self):
        input = self.stdin.readline()
        # here something could be done with input before returning it
        return input

if __name__ == '__main__':

    rep = StdinReplacement()
    while True:
        info = None
        try:
            try:
                input = raw_input("Input something: ")
                print input
            except:
                info = sys.exc_info()
                print info
        except:
            print '\n'
            print "0:", traceback.print_traceback(*info)
            print "1:", traceback.print_exception(*sys.exc_info())
```

Which results in the following being printed out:

```
0:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stdin_issues.py", line 19, in <module>
    input = raw_input("Input something: ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
 None
1:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stdin_issues.py", line 23, in <module>
    print info
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Am I missing something obvious? Maybe intercepting the input in a bad way?

Found this fairly old page which seems like the same issue. No solution though:
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-October/555375.html

Some environment details:
Python 2.7.3 (64-bit), 
Windows 7 SP1 (64-bit)

## ------------------------------------------------------------------------

EDIT:
An update to the readline method of StdinReplacement fixed the issue.

```
def readline(self):
    input = self.stdin.readline()
    # here something could be done with input before returning it
    if len(input) > 0:
        return input
    else:
        return '\n'
```

Comment: My guess is that `raw_input` still uses `sys.stdin`, which is now bound to something that isn't a file object, and so can no longer handle the EOF that is caused by (and precedes) the interrupt.  Try inheriting `StdinReplacement` from `file` to see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem is that your `readline` method returns an empty line, thus signaling the end of file:

```
import sys

class Test(object):
    def readline(self):
        return ''

sys.stdin = Test()

raw_input('')   # EOFError!
```

However modifying it such that it doesn't return an empty line makes the code work:

```
import sys

class Test(object):
    def readline(self):
        return '\n'  # or 'a', or whatever

sys.stdin = Test()

raw_input('')   # no error
```

The `readline` method should return an empty string *only* when the file finished. The `EOFError` is used to mean exactly this: `raw_input` expected the file to contain a line, but the file ended.

---

This is due to the call to `PyFile_GetLine` found at the [end of the implementation of `raw_input`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1c42f1ff2439/Python/bltinmodule.c#l2090):

```
return PyFile_GetLine(fin, -1);
```

According to the documentation of [`PyFile_GetLine(PyObject *p, int n)`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/file.html?highlight=pyfile_asfile#PyFile_GetLine):

> If `n` is less than `0`, however, one line is read regardless of length,
>   but `EOFError` is raised if the end of the file is reached immediately.

Since it passes `-1` as `n` the `EOFError` is raised when the `EOF` is found (i.e. you return an empty string from `readline`).

---

As far as I can tell the behaviour you see is only possible if you insert the input and also create an interrupt. Pressing only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't generate any `EOFError` (at least on linux).

Comment: Thank you for the help. Adding a check on len(input) before returning fixed my problem.